# Google reCaptcha - empty error message, not receiving response to challenge (The reCAPTCHA wasn't entered correctly)

Tags: php, html, recaptcha

EDIT: I'm using reCaptcha 2.0, should I not be using recaptchalib.php?

**Live DEMO**
http://josiahbertoli.com/

I'm getting the following error when I submit a form (ignore the blank values for the input fields)(with debug code):

**Error**

```
_POST: =========
Array
(
    [first_name] => 
    [last_name] => 
    [email] => 
    [subject] => 
    [comments] => 
    [g-recaptcha-response] => big-long-value
)

=========
```

The reCAPTCHA wasn't entered correctly. Go back and try it again.(reCAPTCHA said: )`

How my webpage is set up:

**HTML**

```
<form id="query-form" action="wp-content/themes/portfolio/submit-form.php" method="post" name="myForm">
    <input id="first_name" name="first_name" size="35" type="text" placeholder="e.g. John" />
    <input id="last_name" name="last_name" size="35" type="text" placeholder="e.g. Smith" />
    <input id="email" name="email" size="35" type="text" placeholder="e.g. example@domain.com" />
    <input id="subject" name="subject" size="35" type="text" placeholder="e.g. Feedback" />
    <textarea id="comments" name="comments"></textarea>
    <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="6Le8WxcTAAAAAGqymotU9wtOBFEmWgjM3j2kqTcB"></div>

    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Submit uses method POST to call the action submit-form.php which is as follows

**PHP**

```
<?php
require_once('recaptchalib.php'); 
$privatekey = "the-key-that-i-put-in"; 
echo "<pre> _POST: =========\n"; print_r($_POST); echo "\n=========\n</pre>";
$resp = recaptcha_check_answer ($privatekey, $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"], 
    $_POST["recaptcha_challenge_field"], 
    $_POST["recaptcha_response_field"]); 
$resp = null;
if (!$resp->is_valid) { 
// What happens when the CAPTCHA was entered incorrectly 
    die ("The reCAPTCHA wasn't entered correctly. Go back and try it again." . "(reCAPTCHA said: " . $resp->error . ")"); } 
    else { 
        // Your code here to handle a successful verification 
        include '../../../../process.php';
    } 

?>
```

Thank you for your responses, I appreciate it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For displaying the reCAPTCHA widget you don't need any library file, you just have to include the necessary JavaScript resource, like this:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>reCAPTCHA demo: Simple page</title>
     <script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js" async defer></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form action="?" method="POST">
      <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="your_site_key"></div>
      <br/>
      <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Here's the reference:

- [Displaying the widget](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/display)

Now comes to your user's response. Since you're using Google reCAPTCHA V2, you should fetch the user's response using the POST parameter **g-recaptcha-response**.

Here's the reference:

- [Verifying the user's response](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/verify)

So your code should be like this:

```
<?php   
    if(isset($_POST['g-recaptcha-response']) && !empty($_POST['g-recaptcha-response'])){
        $privatekey = "YOUR_PRIVATE_KEY";

        //get verified response data
        $param = "https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=".$privatekey."&response=".$_POST['g-recaptcha-response'];
        $verifyResponse = file_get_contents($param);
        $responseData = json_decode($verifyResponse);

        if($responseData->success){
            // success
            echo "success";

        }else{
            // failure
            echo "failure";
        }
    }else{
        // user didn't enter reCAPTCHA
        echo "The reCAPTCHA wasn't entered correctly. Go back and try it again.";
    }
?>
```

Comment: Hi Rajdeep Paul, thank you for your response. 

I've got the code you posted to work except that the else isn't firing when I simply click submit without first entering the recaptcha.

http://josiahbertoli.com have a look for yourself

Comment: @user1395909 Just add an `else` part. I've updated the code.

Comment: @user1395909 Glad I could help. :-) Please mark the answer as *accepted* if it resolved your issue.

Comment: The GET option no longer seems to work. It used to before.. i think ???

i updated to POST option using CURL, and that solved my issue