# Contact form submitting regardless of Recaptcha

Tags: php, recaptcha

Hi I'm trying to install Google Recaptcha onto my contact form. Recaptcha is displaying fine but at the moment the form will submit even if Captcha not attempted.

I've posted the code below, would appreciate any help :)

```
<?php

/* =====================================================
 * change this to the email you want the form to send to
 * ===================================================== */
$email_to = ";
$email_subject = "Contact Form submitted";

if(isset($_POST['email']))
{

    function return_error($error)
    {
        echo $error;
        die();
    }

    // check for empty required fields
    if (!isset($_POST['name']) ||
        !isset($_POST['email']) ||
        !isset($_POST['message'])

)
    {
        return_error('Please fill in all required fields.');
    }

    // form field values
    $name = $_POST['name']; // required
    $email = $_POST['email']; // required
    $contact_number = $_POST['contact_number']; // not required
    $message = $_POST['message']; // required
    $enquiry = $_POST['enquiry'];


    // form validation
    $error_message = "";

    // name
    $name_exp = "/^[a-z0-9 .\-]+$/i";
    if (!preg_match($name_exp,$name))
    {
        $this_error = 'Please enter a valid name.';
        $error_message .= ($error_message == "") ? $this_error : "<br/>".$this_error;
    }        

    $email_exp = '/^[A-Za-z0-9._%-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}$/';
    if (!preg_match($email_exp,$email))
    {
        $this_error = 'Please enter a valid email address.';
        $error_message .= ($error_message == "") ? $this_error : "<br/>".$this_error;
    } 

    // if there are validation errors

    if(strlen($error_message) > 0)
    {
        return_error($error_message);
    }

    // prepare email message
    $email_message = "Form details below.\n\n";

    function clean_string($string)
    {
        $bad = array("content-type", "bcc:", "to:", "cc:", "href");
        return str_replace($bad, "", $string);
    }

    $email_message .= "Enquiry Type: ".clean_string($enquiry)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Name: ".clean_string($name)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Email: ".clean_string($email)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Contact number: ".clean_string($contact_number)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Message: ".clean_string($message)."\n";

    // create email headers
    $headers = 'From: '.$email."\r\n".
    'Reply-To: '.$email."\r\n" .
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
    //var_dump($email_to); var_dump($email_subject); var_dump($email_message); var_dump($headers);  
    if (mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers))
    {
        echo 'Form submitted successfully.';
    }
    else 
    {
        echo 'An error occured. Please try again later.';
        die();        
    }
}
else
{
    echo 'Please fill in all required fields.';
    die();
}
?>

<?php   
    if(isset($_POST['g-recaptcha-response']) && !empty($_POST['g-recaptcha-response'])){
        $privatekey = "";

        //get verified response data
        $param = "https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=".$privatekey."&response=".$_POST['g-recaptcha-response'];
        $verifyResponse = file_get_contents($param);
        $responseData = json_decode($verifyResponse);

        if($responseData->success){
            // success
            echo "success";

        }else{
            // failure
            echo "failure";
        }
    }else{
        // user didn't enter reCAPTCHA
        echo "The reCAPTCHA wasn't entered correctly. Go back and try it again.";
    }
?>
```

Comment: This thread will give you a good head start, [http://stackoverflow.com/a/35250609/5517143](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35250609/5517143)

Comment: Thank you, I've updated my files with the code from there. It displays fine but the form still submits fine even if captcha is not attempted.

Comment: Yes, that's because it's doing server side validation. Please [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/39945525/edit) your question and share your code.

Comment: I've given an answer below. Hopefully this will resolve your issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Walk through the code carefully, both the outermost `if` blocks i.e. `if(isset($_POST['email'])){ ...` and `if(isset($_POST['g-recaptcha-response'])...` will  work independently. You need to place `if(isset($_POST['email'])){ ...` block inside `if(isset($_POST['g-recaptcha-response'])...` block, like this:

```
if(isset($_POST['g-recaptcha-response']) && !empty($_POST['g-recaptcha-response'])){
    $privatekey = "YOUR_PRIVATE_KEY";

    //get verified response data
    $param = "https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=".$privatekey."&response=".$_POST['g-recaptcha-response'];
    $verifyResponse = file_get_contents($param);
    $responseData = json_decode($verifyResponse);

    if($responseData->success){
        // success
        $email_to = '';
        $email_subject = "Contact Form submitted";

        if(isset($_POST['email'])){

            function return_error($error){
                echo $error;
                die();
            }

            // check for empty required fields
            if (!isset($_POST['name']) || !isset($_POST['email']) || !isset($_POST['message'])){
                return_error('Please fill in all required fields.');
            }

            // form field values
            $name = $_POST['name']; // required
            $email = $_POST['email']; // required
            $contact_number = $_POST['contact_number']; // not required
            $message = $_POST['message']; // required
            $enquiry = $_POST['enquiry'];


            // form validation
            $error_message = "";

            // name
            $name_exp = "/^[a-z0-9 .\-]+$/i";
            if (!preg_match($name_exp,$name)){
                $this_error = 'Please enter a valid name.';
                $error_message .= ($error_message == "") ? $this_error : "<br/>".$this_error;
            }        

            $email_exp = '/^[A-Za-z0-9._%-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}$/';
            if (!preg_match($email_exp,$email)){
                $this_error = 'Please enter a valid email address.';
                $error_message .= ($error_message == "") ? $this_error : "<br/>".$this_error;
            } 

            // if there are validation errors

            if(strlen($error_message) > 0){
                return_error($error_message);
            }

            // prepare email message
            $email_message = "Form details below.\n\n";

            function clean_string($string){
                $bad = array("content-type", "bcc:", "to:", "cc:", "href");
                return str_replace($bad, "", $string);
            }

            $email_message .= "Enquiry Type: ".clean_string($enquiry)."\n";
            $email_message .= "Name: ".clean_string($name)."\n";
            $email_message .= "Email: ".clean_string($email)."\n";
            $email_message .= "Contact number: ".clean_string($contact_number)."\n";
            $email_message .= "Message: ".clean_string($message)."\n";

            // create email headers
            $headers = 'From: '.$email."\r\n".
            'Reply-To: '.$email."\r\n" .
            'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
            //var_dump($email_to); var_dump($email_subject); var_dump($email_message); var_dump($headers);  
            if (mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers)){
                echo 'Form submitted successfully.';
            }else{
                echo 'An error occured. Please try again later.';
                die();        
            }
        }else{
            echo 'Please fill in all required fields.';
            die();
        }

    }else{
        // failure
        echo "reCAPTCHA failure";
    }
}else{
    // user didn't enter reCAPTCHA
    echo "The reCAPTCHA wasn't entered correctly. Go back and try it again.";
}
```

Comment: @SideB Glad I could help. ;-) Please *accept* the answer if it resolved your issue.  [How to accept answer on Stack Overflow?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235)